# Peg Solitaire backtracking infinite loop

Tags: java, backtracking

I'm making a peg solitaire resolver with backtracking in java.

This is the method I've done:

```
private void solve(Board board, ArrayList<Movement> solution, Boolean result) {
    ArrayList<Movement> movs = board.getMovements();
    for (Movement movement : movs) {
        if (board.isMovementValid(movement)) {
            board.doMovement(movement);
            if(!board.isSolution()) {
                solution.add(movement);
                solve(board, solution, result);
                result.setValue(false);
            } else {
                result.setValue(true);
            }

        }
    }
    result.setValue(false);
}
```

The problem is that I can't find the solution. Here is the output of the code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BhkLu3qr. As you can see the solution array is incomplete.

Thanks.

Comment: So where's the backtracking part?

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but in order to track back and retry an alternative the step must be taken back:

```
ArrayList<Movement> movs = board.getMovements();
for (Movement movement : movs) {
    if (board.isMovementValid(movement)) {
        board.doMovement(movement);
        solution.add(movement);
        if(!board.isSolution()) {
            solve(board, solution, result);
            // Initialized to result.setValue(false);
            if (result.getValue()) { return; }
        } else {
            result.setValue(true);
            return;
        }
        solution.remove(movement);
        board.undoMovement(movement);
    }
}
result.setValue(false);
```

Also for a more general solution where you are satisfied with the first solution, I have added returns.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an infinite loop.

Comment: I do not know the logic to separate dones from todo candidates. Maybe `solution.remove(movement)` is wrong. Look into other backtracking samples/tutorials to get inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `board.getMovements()` method gives you a list of all possible moves from this point in the game, you're almost there. You just need to stop when you win. I've refactored at bit for clarity.

```
private boolean solve(Board board, ArrayList<Movement> solution) {
    // The base case: if it's already solved, we're done
    if (board.isSolution())
        return true;

    // Get all possible moves from this point
    ArrayList<Movement> movs = board.getMovements();
    for (Movement movement : movs) {
        if (board.isMovementValid(movement)) {
            board.doMovement(movement);
            solution.add(movement);
            if (solve(board, solution))
                // That move led to success :-)
                return true;
            else
                // That move led to failure :-(
                solution.remove(movement);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```